# Почему не работает аннотация для Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, рефлексия, аннотации

При написании REST API на Spring Boot решил порпробовать для всех `path` сделать префикс `/rest` при помощи аннотации, но почему-то не работает, причем старый url теперь тоже не отвечает, значит аннотация все-таки влияет но что-то идет не так. Помогите пожалуйста это исправить, и скажите в чем моя ошибка.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public @interface RestApi {
}

@Configuration
public class ApiConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter webMvcRegistrationsHandlerMapping() {
        return new WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter() {
            @Override
            public RequestMappingHandlerMapping getRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
                return new RequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
                    private final static String API_BASE_PATH = "/rest";

                    @Override
                    protected void registerHandlerMethod(Object handler, Method method, RequestMappingInfo mapping) {
                        Class<?> beanType = method.getDeclaringClass();
                        if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(beanType, RestApi.class) != null) {
                            PatternsRequestCondition apiPattern = new PatternsRequestCondition(API_BASE_PATH)
                                    .combine(mapping.getPatternsCondition());

                            mapping = new RequestMappingInfo(mapping.getName(), apiPattern,
                                    mapping.getMethodsCondition(), mapping.getParamsCondition(),
                                    mapping.getHeadersCondition(), mapping.getConsumesCondition(),
                                    mapping.getProducesCondition(), mapping.getCustomCondition());
                        }

                        super.registerHandlerMethod(handler, method, mapping);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вашей аннотации RestApi достаточно. Если её вешать над контроллерами вот так:

```
@RestApi
public class FooController {

    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    @ResponseBody
    String get() {
        return "OK";
    }

}
```

Если порт на котором развёртывается ваше приложение 8080 то при обращении на http://localhost:8080/rest/foo должно вернуться OK.

Не понятно зачем вам нужен ApiConfig. Скорее всего проблема в нём.

Ещё совет: при запуске приложения в логах можно попробовать посмотреть пути на которые вешаются ваши контроллеры.

Comment: нашел опечатку и заработало, но с ApiConfig без него rest не появляется. По поводу лога большое спасибо очень ценное замечание.